# サーブレットクラスを初期化時にClassNotFoundExceptionが発生する

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

お世話になります。

jspからサーブレットを呼び出すときに500エラーが発生します。
ClassNotFoundExceptionが出ており、
web.xmlの設定、またはjspでのform内のURL指定が誤っているのかと
思いましたが、jspからサーブレットを問題なく呼び出せているソースと
比較したところ、web.xmlの記述などには差異は見られませんでした。

ご助言いただければ幸いです。

以下、ソースコード及びエラーメッセージです。

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Pakutter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Pakutter!!!</h1>
    <form action = "/pakutter/servlet/Login" method = "Post">
    ユーザー名:<input type = "text" name = "name"><br>
    パスワード&nbsp;&nbsp;:<input type = "text" name = "pass"><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "ログイン">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Login.java

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;


import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import model.LoginLogic;
import model.User;


public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // リクエストパラメータの取得
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        // Userインスタンス(ユーザー情報)の生成
        User user = new User(name, pass);

        // ログイン処理
        LoginLogic loginLogic = new LoginLogic();
        boolean isLogin = loginLogic.execute(user);

        // ログイン成功時の処理
        if (isLogin) {

            // ユーザー情報をセッションスコープに保存
            // HttpSessionインスタンスの取得
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            // セッションスコープにインスタンスを保存
            session.setAttribute("loginUser", user);

        }

        // ログイン結果画面にフォワード
        RequestDispatcher dispacher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/LoginResult.jsp");
        dispacher.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

/pakutter/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
                /servlet/Login
            </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

エラーメッセージ

```
HTTPステータス 500 - Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

メッセージ サーブレットクラス servlet.Login を初期化中にエラーが発生しました

説明 The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

例外

javax.servlet.ServletException: サーブレットクラス servlet.Login を初期化中にエラーが発生しました
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

原因

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlet.Login
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

以下に記載するのが正常に動作したコードです。
動作としてはindex.jspで入力された値をResult.javaのサーブレット側で取得し計算を行うというものでClassNotFoundExceptionが発生せず処理を行なうことができました。

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta  charset=UTF-8">
<title>映画料金計算</title>
</head>
```

Result.java

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//@WebServlet("/Result")
public class Result extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int age = -1;

        // リクエストパラメータを取得
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
        String type = request.getParameter("type");

        // Calcクラスのインスタンスを生成
        Calc calc = new Calc();

        // 計算結果を代入
        int result = calc.movieFeeCalc(age, gender, type);

        request.setAttribute("result", result);

        getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/result.jsp").forward(request,
                response);

    }

}
    <body>
    <h1>映画料金を計算しゃす！</h1>
    <form action = "/movieFee/servlet/Result" method = "Post">
    性別:<br>
    男<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "0" required>
    女<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "1"><br>
    年齢:<br>
    <input type = "number" name = "age" required><br>
    タイプ:<br>
    3D<input type = "radio" name = "type" value = "0" required>
    2D<input type = "radio" name = "type" value "1">
    <input type = "submit" value = "計算へ">
    </body>
    </html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Result</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.Result</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Result</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
                /servlet/Result
            </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/138102

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlet.Login
```

と言われているので、

```
/pakutter/WEB-INF/classes/servlet/Login.class
```

ファイルが配置されていないことが原因と考えられます。いかがでしょうか?

Comment: 現在/pakutter/src/servlet/Login.javaとしておりますがWEB-INF下に配置する必要があるという認識でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: ソースではなくclassファイルを配置する必要があります。具体的には、Servletの実行時には、`Login.java`をコンパイルした`Login.class`ファイルを`WEB-INF`下に配置する必要がある、ということです。(場所は回答の通り)

Comment: おっしゃる通り、Classファイルが配置されておりませんでした。ありがとうございました。